# Delete section of data based on one entry in section meeting certain criteria using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have one excel sheet (lets say sheet A) that has data in it, organized into groupings separated by an empty row and grouped by a common entry in column N. Within each grouping, I need to check another excel sheet (lets say sheet B) in a different workbook to see if any of the entries in column A of sheet A matches any entries in sheet B's column C. If any of the column C entries match those of the column A entries in a single grouping of the first sheet, I do not do anything to that grouping. If there are no matches, I need to delete the whole grouping. Below is my attempt, but I am mostly getting confused with 1. how to delete just a grouping and 2. how to call to each sheet/column correctly.

```
Sub DeleteAdjacent()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, Dim wb2 As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Long, Dim lastrow2 As Long, Dim i As Long, Dim j As Long
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx")
    Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets(“Sheet B”)
    Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet A")
    lastrow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = lastrow1 To 1 Step -1
        cell = "N" & j
        cell1 = "N" & (j - 1)
        Do While sh1.Cells(j, cell).Value = sh1.Cells(j, cell1).Value
            For i = lastrow2 To 1 Step -1
                cell2 = "C" & i
                cell3 = "A" & j
                If sh1.Cells(j, cell3).Value = sh2.Cells(i, cell2).Value Then
                    Do While sh1.Cells(j, cell).Value = sh1.Cells(j, cell1).Value
                        sh1.Range(j, cell).EntireRow.Delete
                    Loop
                End If
            Next i
        Loop
    Next j
End Sub
```

Edit: Looking at my attempt more closely, it would actually do the opposite of what I'd want to do. I attempted to delete the entire grouping when there was a match, when I actually want the exact opposite. I think then the part below should be changed.

```
If sh1.Cells(j, cell3).Value = sh2.Cells(i, cell2).Value Then
    Do While sh1.Cells(j, cell).Value = sh1.Cells(j, cell1).Value
        sh1.Range.Cells(j, cell).EntireRow.Delete
    Loop
End If
```

My attempt at correcting this is maybe too simple?

```
If sh1.Cells(j, cell3).Value <> sh2.Cells(i, cell2).Value Then
    Do While sh1.Cells(j, cell).Value = sh1.Cells(j, cell1).Value
        sh1.Range.Cells(j, cell).EntireRow.Delete
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if I were attacking this problem I wouldn't compare A with C and do the group looping check in the same process. It might be easier to get your head around the issue if you create a map of values to groups first. Say a value of 10 exists in groups 1,3 and 5, then you could just check for a 10 and immediately eliminate 3 groups from your future checks. A `Collection` of `Collections` would serve you well for this as the look up by `key` is very fast and you don't have to worry about the number of items it stores.

If you also had a collection of `Ranges` for each group then it would be a simple process of eliminating matching groups and then, in one hit, delete all the remaining `Ranges`.

The code below should do that for you (but as with any row delete code, I'd suggest you back up your raw data first!):

```
Public Sub DeleteAdjacent()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim valueGroupMap As Collection
    Dim groupRanges As Collection
    Dim values As Collection
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim groupRng As Range
    Dim valueCell As Range
    Dim groupCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    'Read the Column A worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet A")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 '+1 to get a blank row at end

    'Define the value map group ranges
    Set valueGroupMap = New Collection
    Set groupRanges = New Collection
    Set groupRng = ws.Cells(1, "N")

    For r = 1 To lastRow

        Set valueCell = ws.Cells(r, "A")
        Set groupCell = ws.Cells(r, "N")

        If Len(CStr(groupCell.Value2)) = 0 Then
            'We've reached the end of a group
            Set rng = ws.Range(groupRng, groupCell.Offset(-1))
            groupRanges.Add rng, CStr(groupRng.Value2)
            Set groupRng = Nothing
        Else
            'We're working within a group
            If groupRng Is Nothing Then
                Set groupRng = groupCell
            End If
            'Create the value to group map
            Set values = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set values = valueGroupMap(CStr(valueCell.Value2))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If values Is Nothing Then
                Set values = New Collection
                valueGroupMap.Add values, CStr(valueCell.Value2)
            End If
            values.Add CStr(groupRng.Value2)

        End If

    Next


    'Read the Column C worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet B")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    For r = 1 To lastRow
        'Check if we have the value
        Set values = Nothing
        Set values = valueGroupMap(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "C").Value2))
        If Not values Is Nothing Then
            'We do, so remove the group ranges from our list
            For Each v In values
                groupRanges.Remove CStr(v)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Create a range of the groups still remaining in the list
    Set rng = Nothing
    For Each groupRng In groupRanges
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = groupRng
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, groupRng)
        End If
    Next

    'Delete that range
    rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. This was actually similar to an idea I had by converting my data to tables in MySQL and doing a similar action, but it's great that there was a way to do this in excel VBA.